# Javascript: Set value from multiple field using 1 function but different values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Help please, my problem is, when i set a value from multiple text field by calling 1 function it duplicates the value. How do i make this different to each other. pardon for my English.

Here is my code

```
//code generate
function guid() {
    return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
    s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}

function s4() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x1000)
   .toString(16)
   .substring(1);
}
var uuid = guid();

$('input:radio[name="judge_option"]').change(function (){
   var j_radio = $(this).val();
   if(j_radio == 'backdoor_access'){
        $('.backdoor_link').val(uuid); //<---- when i fire the trigger 
   }
});
```

The output shows like this

```
<input type="text" class="backdoor_link" value="ae668f-2bf-a24-6a5-58677a007"> 
<input type="text" class="backdoor_link" value="ae668f-2bf-a24-6a5-58677a007"> 
<input type="text" class="backdoor_link" value="ae668f-2bf-a24-6a5-58677a007">
<input type="text" class="backdoor_link" value="ae668f-2bf-a24-6a5-58677a007">
```

How do i make it look like this one, the values that i set should be different to each other in 1 click.

```
<input type="text" class="backdoor_link" value="143e37-cb3-b83-4ef-aca186f3d"> 
<input type="text" class="backdoor_link" value="f3e198-b1c-918-28c-00e29debb"> 
<input type="text" class="backdoor_link" value="bda03e-4e0-da7-f82-36592439c">
<input type="text" class="backdoor_link" value="e73b85-3f0-220-9ec-acffa6ba8">
```

Comment: Why is uuid a global variable then?

Comment: i tried the $('.backdoor_link')‌​.val(guid()); but the values are all same together when i fire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only calling `guid()` once, and you're assigning it to all `.backdoor_link` elements. Pass the function to [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val-function) so that it's called for each `.backdoor_link`:

```
$('.backdoor_link').val(guid);
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u6wag5cq/1/)